Adding navigation block to page creates new, derived menu, instead of using the originally defined menus
I have a problem with the menus on my WordPress site running the virtue theme. Wordpress is the newest version and all plug-ins are up to date. I have not coded anything in any file.
I have three standard menus one for each language) and three menus for mobile.
In a previous version, everything worked fine: I defined the menus in appearance, menus and assigned them to each page. However, ( not sure if that is the reason) once I put the navigation block within a container (plug in = GenerateBlocks 1.9.1) within a cover, on each page, a separate menu has been created (see screenshot).

As you can see, the three menus are repeated each time for each page...
Each has the same name as the original menu, but is specific to this page. I created them, by clicking on the original menu when adding menu to navigation block, but a new menu is created, and I have to save it, otherwise the page does not change.
Hence, once I want to change the navigation, I have to change it by hand on each of dozens of pages, instead of one time in the central menu location. This is very hard to maintain, and I am looking for help to do the following:

Delete the specific menus (How? Where?)
Find a way to use the original, central menus on each page as they are defined in the central menu location like here:


